# Use Multiple Internet connections on the same Computer but for different apps

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, internet, internet-connection

I know this is quite similar to the questions asked before however none of them answered my question. Please read this before downvoting. What I basically want to do is if I have a 4Mbit(on WiFi) line and a 2Mbit line(on ethernet) I want to use the 2Mbit line for dedicated downloading(cloud services, leagal torrents, etc) while the WiFi line is for my normal browsing.

I DO NOT want to merge them, bond them or load balance. I have a normal Linksys EA6500 V2 with a single WAN port and a Dell 3543 running Windows 10. So is this possible?

Update: I read from the comments that it is better to add what I have considered. I had a look at Speedify a service offered by those at connectify to "bond" connections but as I said it does not satisfy the requirements. Then I took a look at those "Dual" WAN routers but again they are extremenely rare and only support load balancing.

Comment: This isn't a service site. To avoid down votes, you should include details about what YOU have done to research it and what you have attempted to accomplish it. If you need more information about [ask], its in the [help].

Comment: I know that, I will add that to the question then. Thanks for the information. While I understand sensible down votes I wrote that because there are users who read the title and think it's a repeat without even reading the rest.

Comment: Are these two different internet connections the questions sounds like it may be but I want to make sure.

Comment: Is this with one router, or two, one NIC, or two, etc.? You need to clearly spell out everything which may be relevant in formulating a solution.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin yes I do plan to get Two Separate connections for the internet. A 2Mbit line and a 4Mbit line but since I have only one router only  the 4Mbit one would be wireless.

Comment: @RonMaupin I have one router, one ethernet NIC and one Wlan card (though I can add more wlan chips) and two separate internet connections from the same ISP

Answer (score 0):

Search about "**ForceBindIP**" in google. I think that's what you need. https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip And BTW, I'm using it right now.

I'm downloading a file using IDM through WiFi-1(My mobile hotspot) and watching a Twitch stream in Firefox simultaneously & separately through WiFi-2(my router which i connected with using a network adapter), without combining both internet connections.

Here is the link to the Tutorial: https://youtu.be/5cxaE4J-8KM